# Present a view controller modally over current context when the view controller gets load from a nib file

Tags: swift, xcode, nib, uimodalpresentationstyle

I need to present view controller B which is being loaded from a xib file over an existing view controller A loaded from storyboard.

If I load view controller B from storyboard it works properly and will be presented over current context of view controller A but if I load it from nib file it won't present over current context.

load from nib:

```
let vc = ViewControllerB()
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

load from storyboard:

```
let vc: ViewControllerB = ViewControllerB.instantiate()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
(tabBarController as? TabBarController)?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

TabBarController is my custom controller.

If I load it from xib file, view controller B is fully presented on top of view controller A so that the presentation style is not over current context, I expect still to see the beneath view or view controller A. There are many related posts here but none of them referring to presenting a view controller made by xib file over current view controller context.

Answer (score 0):

Loading view via storyboard or nib file doesn't make any difference to present a view modally over current context, in my case I changed the background color of my parent controller to be visible in top from the child controller.